# I got NAs error when applying lasso model to the recipe

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression, r-recipes

I was trying to apply a lasso model to a recipe I created (using `recipes` package) but I am getting the error:

> NAs introduced by coercion
> Error in lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y,
> weights, offset, alpha, nobs, : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call
> (arg 5)

Here is the recipe I created:

```
c_recipe <- recipe(c ~ ., 
                   data = train) %>%
  step_rm(customer_id, billing_postal, billing_address,billing_city) %>%
  step_novel(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_impute_mean(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_impute_mode(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors())

c_recipe
```

Here is how I applied the model:

```
lasso_spec <- logistic_reg(penalty = 0.1, mixture = 1) %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

logistic_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(churn_recipe) %>%
  add_model(lasso_spec) %>%
  fit(train)
```

Comment: If you can create a [small reproducible example](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/) that demonstrates your problem, that would make it possible for others to help you out.